# Not able to filter table with multiple rows

Tags: html, jquery

FACING ISSUE IN CREATING MULTIPLE TABLE FILTERS IN HTML TABLE.

Following is the HTML code wherein I'm trying to filter out data on the basis of 3 columns(here, table has a total of 4 columns). The last column is just a URL hence doesn't need filtering.

But the filters aren't working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Problems Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        var $filterableRows = $('#tableF').find('tr').not(':first'),
        
        $inputs = $('.search-key');

        $inputs.on('input', function() {

            $filterableRows.hide().filter(function() {
            var $filterableColumns = $(this).find('td').not(':last');
            return $filterableColumns.filter(function() {
                
              var tdText = $(this).text().toLowerCase(),
                    inputValue = $('#' + $(this).data('input')).val().toLowerCase();
            
                return tdText.indexOf(inputValue) != -1;
            
            }).length == $filterableColumns.length-1;
          }).show();

        });
        </script>
    
    

    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <h1 style="text-align:right;"><strong>CODER'S GYM</strong></h1>
    <section class="ftco-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center mb-5">
                    <h2 class="heading-section"><i><u>Problems Arena</u></i></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4 class="text-center mb-4">Click on <strong>Try</strong> to Solve</h4>
                    
                    <input type="text" id="Code" class="search-key" placeholder="Code">
                    <input type="text" id="Title" class="search-key" placeholder="Title">
                    <input type="text" id="Difficulty" class="search-key" placeholder="Difficulty">
                    
                    
                    <div class="table-wrap">
                        <table id="tableF">
                        <thead class="thead-primary">
                          <tr>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Difficulty</th>
                            <th>Try</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td data-input="Code">ABC</th>
                            <td data-input="Title">Two Sum</td>
                           
                            <td data-input="Difficulty" >Easy</td>
                           
                            
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td data-input="Code">BCD</th>
                            <td data-input="Title">Add Two Numbers</td>
                           
                            <td data-input="Difficulty" >Medium</td>
                           
                            
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td data-input="Code">CDE</th>
                            <td data-input="Title">Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters</td>
                          
                            <td data-input="Difficulty" >Medium</td>
                           
                            
                            <td><a href=#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td data-input="Code">DEF</th>
                            <td data-input="Title">Median of Two Sorted Arrays</td>
                            
                            <td data-input="Difficulty" >Hard</td>                          
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td data-input="Code">EFG</th>
                            <td data-input="Title">Longest Palindromic Substring </td>
                          
                            <td data-input="Difficulty" >Medium</td>
                           
                            
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td border-bottom-0" data-input="Code">FGH</th>
                            <td class="border-bottom-0" data-input="Title">Zingzag Conversion</td>
                           
                            <td class="border-bottom-0" data-input="Difficulty" >Medium</td>
                         
                            <td class="border-bottom-0"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    

    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried all the things here, but still the code isn't working. I'd be glad if someone could help to resolve this issue as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Problems Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
   
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $filterableRows = $('#tableF').find('tr').not(':first'),
        
        $inputs = $('.search-key');

        $inputs.on('input', function() {

            $filterableRows.hide().filter(function() {
            var $filterableColumns = $(this).find('td').not(':last');
            return $filterableColumns.filter(function() {
                
              var tdText = $(this).text().toLowerCase(),
                    inputValue = $('#' + $(this).data('input')).val().toLowerCase();
            
                return tdText.indexOf(inputValue) != -1;
            
            }).length == $filterableColumns.length-1;
          }).show();

        });
    });
    </script>
    
    

    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <h1 style="text-align:right;"><strong>CODER'S GYM</strong></h1>
    <section class="ftco-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center mb-5">
                    <h2 class="heading-section"><i><u>Problems Arena</u></i></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4 class="text-center mb-4">Click on <strong>Try</strong> to Solve</h4>
                    
                    <input type="text" id="Code" class="search-key" placeholder="Code">
                    <input type="text" id="Title" class="search-key" placeholder="Title">
                    <input type="text" id="Difficulty" class="search-key" placeholder="Difficulty">
                    
                    
                    <div class="table-wrap">
                        <table id="tableF">
                        <thead class="thead-primary">
                          <tr>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Difficulty</th>
                            <th>Try</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td data-input="Code">ABC</th>
                            <td data-input="Title">Two Sum</td>
                           
                            <td data-input="Difficulty" >Easy</td>
                           
                            
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td data-input="Code">BCD</th>
                            <td data-input="Title">Add Two Numbers</td>
                           
                            <td data-input="Difficulty" >Medium</td>
                           
                            
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td data-input="Code">CDE</th>
                            <td data-input="Title">Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters</td>
                          
                            <td data-input="Difficulty" >Medium</td>
                           
                            
                            <td><a href=#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td data-input="Code">DEF</th>
                            <td data-input="Title">Median of Two Sorted Arrays</td>
                            
                            <td data-input="Difficulty" >Hard</td>                          
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td data-input="Code">EFG</th>
                            <td data-input="Title">Longest Palindromic Substring </td>
                          
                            <td data-input="Difficulty" >Medium</td>
                           
                            
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td border-bottom-0" data-input="Code">FGH</th>
                            <td class="border-bottom-0" data-input="Title">Zingzag Conversion</td>
                           
                            <td class="border-bottom-0" data-input="Difficulty" >Medium</td>
                         
                            <td class="border-bottom-0"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Try</a></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    

    </body>
</html>
```

We put all you javascript inside `$(document).ready(function() {});` In this way, html table object is rendered, and ready to be filtered.

And also I suggest you to use the last jQuery code, that is at our day, jquery 3.6.0.

Comment: Thank you so much Jacouh for helping. Yes, it is working now. Had been trying it for hours. Thanks again.

Comment: Great, if this solved your problem, please not hesitate to check this is anwser...